# Internet Explorer Websockets that connect to a server through proxy cause crashes

Tags: javascript, proxy, websocket, socket.io, internet-explorer-11

I've been creating a site that's meant to work on all browsers, and connects to a nodejs server through a proxy (meaning, the client connects to the server through a proxy) using websockets.

The site works fine on all browsers, but I've noticed some strange behavior on IE. The more the client browsed through the site, and as a result, opened more websockets, the slower the tab the client was browsing through became. Eventually, the tab would stop responding entirely and had to be shut down entirely because it'd stop responding.

I tried to whittle the problem down as much as I could, and eventually noticed that when your browser uses an explicit proxy, and has websockets, after a set amount of connections (around 25) the tab you're using will stop being able to connect to the server, and may stop working altogether. It's easy to reproduce this using the following steps:

1. Take the example page from [here](https://www.websocket.org/echo.html) and create an html page
2. Download fiddler and use it as your proxy
3. Browse to the example page that you created and keep refreshing your tab. You should notice a slowness, until an eventual stop

It's worth noting that without a proxy, the tab will not end up dying like this.

Has anyone else encountered this issue? If so, is there any fix to this, aside from changing the architecture?

Thanks a lot